# ORA-01722 invalid number though types should match

Tags: oracle

table1 dwh.fct_nc_crm_dims@etl4

```
Name                        Null     Type          
--------------------------- -------- ------------- 
BAN_KEY                     NOT NULL NUMBER(9)     
CLIENT_NAME                          VARCHAR2(300) 
CLIENT_INN                           VARCHAR2(40)  
EFFECTIVE_DATE              NOT NULL DATE          
EXPIRATION_DATE                      DATE
```

table2 etl.stg_acrm_ban_attr@etl2

```
Name             Null Type          
---------------- ---- ------------- 
SEGMENT_CRM           VARCHAR2(150) 
BAN_KEY               VARCHAR2(32)
```

table3 evkuzmin_b2b_churn_ban_segment

```
Name        Null Type          
----------- ---- ------------- 
BAN_KEY          NUMBER(9)     
CLIENT_NAME      VARCHAR2(300) 
CLIENT_INN       VARCHAR2(40)  
SEGMENT_CRM      VARCHAR2(150)
```

My query. Here I join first 2 tables on ban_key and insert the result into the third table. The types match, but I still get the error. Why?

```
INSERT INTO evkuzmin_b2b_churn_ban_segment
SELECT a.ban_key, a.client_name, a.client_inn, b.segment_crm FROM(
  SELECT ban_key, client_name, client_inn
  FROM(
    SELECT ban_key,client_name, client_inn, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ban_key, client_inn ORDER BY effective_date DESC) AS rn
    FROM dwh.fct_nc_crm_dims@etl4 
    WHERE expiration_date >= TO_DATE('01.04.2016','DD.MM.YYYY') OR expiration_date IS NULL --1ST DAY OF REPORTING PERIOD
  )
  WHERE rn = 1
) a, etl.stg_acrm_ban_attr@etl2 b 
WHERE a.ban_key = b.ban_key;
```

Comment: Look for non-number data in etl.stg_acrm_ban_attr@etl2.ban_key: `SELECT
    t2.ban_key
FROM
    etl.stg_acrm_ban_attr@etl2 t2
WHERE
        1 = 1
    AND
        REGEXP_LIKE ( t2.ban_key,'[^[:digit:]]' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ban_key in evkuzmin_b2b_churn_ban_segment(table 3) is a Number as compare to the other two tables(varchar).

your a.ban_key is number and b.ban_key is varchar

Comment: In `evkuzmin_b2b_churn_ban_segment` `ban_key` is number. I take it from `fct_nc_crm_dims` where it is also number. But in `stg_acrm_ban_attr` it is varchar. I tried to do `a.ban_key = TO_NUMBER(b.ban_key);`, but got the same error.

Comment: error seems to be thrown by- WHERE a.ban_key = b.ban_key;

Comment: your a.ban_key is number and b.ban_key is varchar

Comment: Looks like `etl.stg_acrm_ban_attr@etl2` contains a string that is not convertable to a number.

Comment: try TO_CHAR(a.ban_key) =b.ban_key